# Remove element from jquery object not yet registered to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I'm building a Symfony2 application that uses a [form collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), where users can add forms on the fly. To dynamically add forms, Symfony2 gives us a way to get the form template in javascript, and we just need to replace `__name__` placeholder by the current index.

As my form requires some very specific layout, I needed to merge errors with the widget, and now I'm stuck when I want to remove errors from the template if it was initialized with some.

I can simplify my problem this way:

```js
/* js */
var test = $('<div><p class="error">Dirty stuff</p><p>Clean stuff</p></div>').remove('.error');
$('#test').append(test);
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

As you can see, the output is:

```
Dirty stuff
Clean stuff
```

Instead of just:

```
Clean stuff
```

My question:

> How can I remove everything that match my `.error` selector from my `test` var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're saying you want to do this:

```js
var test = $('<div><p class="error">Dirty stuff</p><p>Clean stuff</p></div>');

test.find(".error").remove();

$("#test").append(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

There are a number of different ways to phrase this, but basically after you've created the elements but before we append them, we do a `.find()` to locate the `.error` elements, and then remove them.

Then we simply append the original `test`, because its `.error` descendants were removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the dom and remove later:

```
$('#test').append('<div><p class="error">Dirty stuff</p><p>Clean stuff</p></div>');
$('.error').remove();
```

Comment: I don't want to remove all already dom-registered `.error`. Thanks anyway